# Display Please wait or processing message to user once the form is filled in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I am creating a registration form in AngularJS, wherein once the admin fills the form and on submit, I am doing two things: 1. Saving the data into the DB. 2. Sending an email to the person with his username and password. So on submitting my application is taking some time (around 5-7 seconds) to post the success message back on the screen. So I want to show some message while these background operations complete. I need your help as I am new to AngularJS.

```
createUserService.Register(obj, function(data) {
                        if (data.error) {
                            console.log("Check " + data.error);
                        } else {
                           alertify.alert("Successfully Registered");
                            $state.reload();
                        }
```

This is my service:

```
function Register(obj, callback) {
            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : '/api/addUserOps',
                data : obj
            }).then(function(response) {
                callback(response.data);
            }, function(error) {
                callback(error);
            });
        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way.

**Service function**

```
function Register(obj) {
  return $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/api/addUserOps',
            data : obj
        });
}
```

**Calling your function**

```
    // Trying using https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy for showing a loader here.
   createUserService.Register(obj)
   .then(function(data){
     // stop your loader here with a success message.
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
    // your error message here. 
   })
```

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Hi Shaul, Thanks for the answer. However, when I do the same as suggested above, I am getting the this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: Are your returning the $http call in your Register service function?